# Imagem no Json sem usar Base 64

Tags: json

Olá

Eu estou a criar um json e em cada informação do json preciso de colocar uma imagem mas eu não queria um código gigante por isso **Não quero usar base64** existe alguma maneira de colocar um link no json que leva para uma imagem?

A imagem no json irá passar por um filtro feito em javascript por isso não sei se posso por o url da imagem na tag img.

```js
[
    {
        "titulo": "Texto titulo",
        "localizacao": "Texto localização",
        "texto": "Texto grande de exemplo para usar como teste geral",
        "imagem": "",
        "id": 0
    }
]
```

**Edição**

```js
[    
    {
        "titulo": "Teste 1",
        "imagem": "imagens/Exemplo.png",
        "id": 0
    },

    {
        "titulo": "Teste 2",
        "imagem": "imagens/sardinha11.png",
        "id": 1
    }
]
```

```html
<img class="imageminfo" id="imagemareas" src="imagens/Exemplo.png">
```

Coloquei dessa forma e depois o meu script tem uma função e no final dela eu uso esta forma para editar a imagem:

```js
var image: obj.imagem;

$("#imagemareas").text(this.image);
```

O script não está completo pois ha diferentes scripts deste genero que acho que não e preciso apresentar ou a pergunta ia ficar muito grande.

**Reposta**

Com ajuda de algumas resposta consegui realizar a minha solução:

```js
[    
    {
        "titulo": "1",
        "imagem": "./imagens/Exemplo.png",
        "id": 0

    },

    {
        "titulo": "2",
        "imagem": "./imagens/sardinha11.png",
        "id": 1
    }
]

var image: obj.imagem;

$("#imagemareas").attr("src", this.image);
```

```html
<img class="imageminfo" id="imagemareas" src="">
```

Comment: sim, no json basta usar `"imagem": "http://algumdominio/imagem.jpg"`, depois só setar o `src` da imagem com o link

Comment: @RicardoPontual mas o http leva para uma imagem no pc?

Comment: se vc quiser uma imagem local deveria colocar na pergunta para ajudar. No caso de imagem local pode usar o caminho relativo: `src=image.jpg` ou `src=../imagems/imagem.jpg"`

Comment: @RicardoPontual continua sem funcionar existe alguma forma de lhe poder partilhar o meu codigo para voce poder dar uma olhada para ver o que se está a passar?

Comment: você pode editar a pergunta e colocar aqui, também ajuda outras pessoas a entender e propor outras soluções :)

Comment: Ja consegui resolver obrigada irei colocar a solução na pergunta

Answer (score 4):

Suponhamos que o seu arquivo que irá exibir a imagem esteja em qualquer lugar, seja remoto ou localhost, e suponhamos que dentro do diretório de arquivos você tem um subdiretório chamado "imagens".

A estrutura do Json ficará:

```
[
 {
        "titulo": "Texto titulo",
        "localizacao": "Texto localização",
        "texto": "Texto grande de exemplo para usar como teste geral",
        "imagem": "imagens/arquivo.jpg",
        "id": 0
  }
]
```

Se você chamar na tag  o src="" com o nome do caminho, a tag exibirá a imagem relacionada, tanto faz se está em localhost ou na web, se a estrutura de arquivos e diretórios forem as mesmas, você não terá problema algum em exibir as imagens no seu código, pois manterá o padrão do caminho do arquivo como imagens/arquivo.jpg.

Em localhost ficará:

```
<img src="imagens/arquivo.jpg"/>
```

E no servidor online ficará:

```
<img src="imagens/arquivo.jpg"/>
```

E ambos os locais exibirão as imagens do mesmo modo.

Comment: a imagem ira passar por um filtro que fiz feito em javascript logo a imagem que vai estar na tag <img> irá mudar consuante o obj escolhido por isso é que queria por a imagem so no json e não na tag

Comment: O exemplo acima é exatamente isso, ele ficará referenciado no json, e o seu javascript recebe o valor de img: do json e envia para a tag img src='', não ficará estático, usei o exemplo da tag como o resultado final.

Comment: vou tentar ja lhe digo alguma coisa.

Comment: Eliseu eu coloquei desse metedo mas a imagem não muda com os filtros escolhidos irei editar a pergunta para lhe mostrar

Comment: É possível você disponibilizar seu código JavaScript, melhorar sua pergunta com mais detalhes do seu código?

Comment: é sim prefere que eu use o que para colocar o meu codigo lá?